# How to save a list and access values in a list in Python--- .txt file

Tags: python, list, text

I want to create a module that checks whether a number is prime or not, and to list all of the primes before it.

The functions in the module would take a bit of time if it had to generate the list of primes every single time it was created.

How do I open a .txt file that is in the same folder as the program is in, then have it access the data from it and create a list based off of that? The .txt file will be saved a list afterwards when the function is completed. I also need a bit of guidance on how to actually save the file in a given location.

Any suggestions or tips would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pickle a `set` object, you could do this:

```
import cPickle as pickle

primes_set = set([2,3,5])

pickle.dump(primes_set, open('primes_set.pkl', 'wb')) 

my_primes = pickle.load(open('primes_set.pkl', 'rb')) # to load the object
```

After you created a pickle file, you could use it like this:

```
def get_primes(my_nums):
    '''
    Return only prime numbers from inputted list.
    '''
    my_primes = pickle.load(open('primes_set.pkl', 'rb'))
    return [num for num in my_nums if num in my_primes]
```

Comment: Is it possible to pickle a `list` object though? That would work out better in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, you could pickle a list just like you would a set.

Comment: It's definitely worth learning pickle. In this case, where you're just saving a flat list, there are other solutions that are just as easy. But one day, you'll have a complicated deeply-nested structure to save, and you'll be glad you know how to do it in one line.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at io in python
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

as you seem to be doing number crunching i would use pytables (hdf5 binary file) to save load and update arrays

http://www.pytables.org/moin

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.  If you want to save the list as a list, the [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is probably the best way to go.

If you don't mind processing your txt file then you could just store it as a [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv), which python will turn back into a list readily.

Comment: Looking the in the Pickle module document, I see there's an easy way of using just `pickle.dump(object, file)` and `object = pickle.load(file)`. What is the format of the `file` parameter? Is it the directory location of the file on my hard drive? Or is it the name of the file? Thanks!

Comment: Those are file-like-objects.  The "normal" way to get a file like object is to use open() and open a file on a disk, but you can get them in other ways such as the tempfile module or by using StringIO.

Answer (score 1):

In order to open a file, just use

```
filereader = open("example.txt")
```

then the variable filereader will contain the file's data.

```
allprimes = []
for line in filereader:
    allprimes.append(int(line)) #assuming one number is stored per line
```

allprimes will now contain all numbers stored in the file.

Comment: OK I see how that would work. How would I save the file though? And how do I get Python to save the `.txt` file as just one number per line?